# Why does this crystal oscillator have a window?

Tags: crystal, packages

I came across [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epson/SG-3040LC-32.7680KB3-PURE-SN/SER3697TR-ND/2403389) device just now, and I can't think of any reason for it to have the window that it has.

[image: A 12-pin SO package of some sort, with a glass window on its underside.]

This isn't just a cutaway display image, either; the datasheet specifically mentions that you should avoid getting glue under it to avoid cracking the glass:

[image: A section of the datasheet, saying that you should avoid using glue lest it crack the glass.]

So, what is the purpose of this window? Surely it increases the cost of manufacture, so it wouldn't be there without some good purpose, right?

I can't see it being for trimming, either, as [what seems to be exactly the same part](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epson/SG-3040JC-32.7680KB3-ROHS/SER3696TR-ND/2403388) is also offered in a different package that doesn't have a window.

Comment: Probably some type of trimming of the frequency has to be done in manufacturing after packaging.  Once the trimming is done the window goes on.  Or possibly the part can be laser trimmed through the window, though I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: @JohnD I looked into that after you commented and found that the same part is sold in packages without such a window as well, so while it was a "wait why didn't I think of that" level of obvious answer, it doesn't seem to be the right one. Details appended to the question.

Comment: Another guess: the window package is low-profile (1.2mm) others are thicker. I'm wondering how a lead-frame can be encapsulated in pure epoxy and still leave wiggle-room for the tuning-fork? Maybe a pure-epoxy mold requires more height than a thin-glass cap to assure clearance.

Comment: Is it possible that Digikey shows a windowed version only to illustrate what is inside the package? Rather than to suggest you can get windowed parts? The datasheet they link doesn't (to my reading, anyway) show a windowed option.

Comment: Oh well, guess not then.  Sounds like @glen_geek may be on to something though.

Comment: @jonk I've added an image highlighting the part where the datasheet mentions the use of glass in the package. A cutaway view was my first thought as well, though I've never seen digi-key do one before, but seeing that in the datasheet was what really made me wonder.

Comment: @glen_geek Hmm, that would make sense.

Comment: Well it can't so we can see if it's vibrating (Only kidding - the glass will be facing the PCB.) I'd go with the laser trimming. Remembering that the old EPROMS had quartz windows on them that passed UV you might find that these are UV laser trimmed.

Comment: @Transistor What do you say to the fact that it also comes in packages without a window, then?

Comment: @Felthry: I say nothing!

Comment: The tutorial from Epson https://www.digikey.com/en/ptm/e/epson/spxo-and-vcxo/tutorial implies that the crystal is encapsulated in a ceramic package and that the chip is either inside this package or the package and chip are embedded in a plastic package. I am guessing that the lowest profile is obtained when one side of the ceramic package is exposed and that this glass is part of the ceramic package. Perhaps it isn't practical to encapsulate a crystal in plastic alone?

Comment: @SteveHubbard has it right.  The crystal has to be hermetically sealed preventing gas migration into the chamber, so plastic alone will not work.  Glass is an excellent material for creating gas-tight hermetic seals with through-conductors.

Comment: @SteveHubbard Could you write that up as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you!

Comment: @JohnBirckhead I did ask Steve to write it as an answer, but I think you might have something to add too, so I thought I'd give you a ping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@SteveHubbard has it right. The crystal has to be hermetically sealed preventing gas migration into the chamber, so plastic alone will not work. Glass is an excellent material for creating gas-tight hermetic seals with through-conductors.  The crystal chamber will be filled with a dry inert gas or a vacuum.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial from Epson digikey.com/en/ptm/e/epson/spxo-and-vcxo/tutorial implies that the crystal is encapsulated in a ceramic package and that the chip is either inside this package or the package and chip are embedded in a plastic package. I am guessing that the lowest profile is obtained when one side of the ceramic package is exposed and that this glass is part of the ceramic package. Perhaps it isn't practical to encapsulate a crystal in plastic alone?